# Call vue-html-to-paper print function on a new window

Tags: vue.js, dom, printing, vue-component, printing-web-page

I have a Vue component I'd like to print. When the user presses a `print` button, a function is called which opens the component in a new window to isolate the HTML, and get the formatting right.

```js
    async openPrintDetailsDialogue() {
      const prtHtml = document.getElementById('printable').innerHTML;
      let stylesHtml = '';
      for (const node of [...document.querySelectorAll('link[rel="stylesheet"], style')]) {
        stylesHtml += node.outerHTML;
      }
      var newWindow = window.open('', '', 'left=0,top=0,width=800,height=900,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
      newWindow.document.write(`<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
          <head>
            ${stylesHtml}
          </head>
          <body id="printme">
            ${prtHtml}
          </body>
        </html>`);
      newWindow.document.close();
      newWindow.focus();
      ...
```

I then try to print using `$htmlToPaper`.

```js
      ...
      await this.$htmlToPaper('printme');
      newWindow.close();
    }
```

However, the main window alerts  `Element to print #printme not found!`.

I add the plugin `VueHtmlToPaper` in my `mounted()` function:

```js
  mounted() {
    Vue.use(VueHtmlToPaper);
  }
```

I've already tried passing my existing `styles.css` to the `$htmlToPaper()` call `options`, which changed nothing. I also have some styles in my `vue` file's `<style scoped>`, which couldn't be included in the `options` parameter either.

How can I get `VueHtmlToPaper` to "point" to `newWindow`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By opening a new window you have a new separate webpage, where is no Vue Js instance. It does not work so and you will not make it work this way. You should use a Modal, change the current page or make a new page with Vue instance for printing.